# How to import package in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I use pyspark for data processing. After I load data in DataFrame, some columns have json-encoded string, while I want to take part of them.

My current code :

```
def f(column_name):
    import simplejson as json
    column_list = json.loads(column_name)
    return column_list[0] if column_list else ""

F = udf(f, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("new_A", F(df["A"]))
```

It will return error like :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 505, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
```

If I remove json part but simply return origin string, it works fine.

So I guess sth wrong with import package in pyspark, what should I do to import package like simlejson, pickle, ...?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe [this helps](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/spark_python.html)

Comment: Thanks mtoto, just one question, is this the general way to deal with package import for python spark? As in non-spark python app (like django maybe), there are always many package to import (like datetime, json, pickle, logging...), it seem very difficult to put many .egg files to call it, so is there any simple way?

Comment: you should install the packages in your enviromnent as described at the bottom of the link.